# how can i change a panel border width in ext js 3.4?

Tags: extjs, width, border, panel

how do i change a panel border width? in ext 3.4  api border is a boolean.

**My code**

```
var p = new Ext.Panel({
    title  : 'My Panel',       
    width  :400,
    border : true //default also true.

});
```

how can i edit border width for example 2px or 3px??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use CSS, Ext will account for it when calculating the component size and laying it out.

First, put a custom CSS class on your panel:

```
var p = new Ext.Panel({
    title: 'My Panel',       
    width:400,
    border: true //default also true.

    ,cls: 'my-panel'
});
```

Then style it:

```
.x-panel.my-panel {
    border: 5px solid red;
}
```